# putting significance levels over various facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a bar graph with various facets using `ggplot2` and `facet_wrap`.
I have been using `geom_signif` which is very handy in the most part.

The graph is similar to this:

```
value <- sample(1 :50,100,replace = T)
B <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,2,1),  50) )
C <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2),each=100) )
A <- as.factor(rep(c(4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1), 25) )

dt1 <- data.frame(A,B,C,value) %>%
  group_by(A,B,C)

ggplot(dt1, aes(x=A, y=value, fill=(B))) +theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(C))  +
  geom_boxplot(position='dodge',outlier.size=0) +geom_point(size=0.5,position=position_jitterdodge(0.2))    +
  geom_signif(data = dt1 %>% group_by(A,B), 
              y_position = 55, xmin = 0.8, xmax = 0.8, 
              annotation = rep("*"), tip_length = 0.02) 

ggplot(dt1, aes(x=A, y=value, fill=(B))) +theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(C))  +
  geom_boxplot(position='dodge',outlier.size=0) +geom_point(size=0.5,position=position_jitterdodge(0.2))    +
  geom_signif(data = dt1 %>% group_by(A,B), 
              y_position = 55, xmin = 0.8, xmax = 4.8, 
              annotation = rep("*"), tip_length = 0.02)
```

[image]

[image]

My question is: How do I create a significance level over two values that stem from two different facets? For instance, '1' in facet 1 and '1' in facet 2 in the example.
I do not manage to set the xmax values to grap the subsequent facet as the x-axis is repeated in all facets.
The desired outcome would draw one single line from A=1 to A=1 from one facet to the other and place the sign * in the middle of the line. Similar to the second plot I posted but at the positions of the first plot.

Switching the fill and facet variables is not an option.

As you may see, I have already tried to ungroup the corresponding variable C with data = group_by(...) but this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues/22) there seems no inbuilt option. You could use `ggplot_build` to modify the data behind your first plot, so that you can connect the line from panel 1 to panel 2. For this you need to change the `x` and `xend` values of the plot and set the layout clip to 'off' to make lines across facets. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(7) # reproducibility
value <- sample(1 :50,100,replace = T)
B <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,2,1),  50) )
C <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2),each=100) )
A <- as.factor(rep(c(4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1), 25) )

dt1 <- data.frame(A,B,C,value) %>%
  group_by(A,B,C)

p <- ggplot(dt1, aes(x=A, y=value, fill=(B))) +theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(C))  +
  geom_boxplot(position='dodge',outlier.size=0) +geom_point(size=0.5,position=position_jitterdodge(0.2))    +
  geom_signif(data = dt1 %>% group_by(A,B), 
              y_position = 55, xmin = 0.8, xmax = 4.8, 
              annotation = rep("*"), tip_length = 0.02)

# Use ggplot_build
q <- ggplot_build(p)  

# Modify data
q$data[[3]]$xend <- c(0.8, 5.8, 5.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
q$data[[3]]$x <- c(0.8, 0.8, 6.8, 0.8, 0, 0.8)
q$data[[3]]$annotation <- c(rep('*', 3), rep('', 3))

# Add data back to plot
q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
# Change clip layout
q$layout$clip <- 'off'
# plot data again
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, there is a comparison across facets.

Comment: Looks exactly as what I was looking for. Actually, I was hoping for an easier builtin solution. It would have been too good just to select the number of the facet in xmax somehow :)

Comment: As I will need to implement this into a more complex data set. For my understanding: Where does the value 3 come from in here? q$data[[3]]$annotation <- c(rep('*', 3), rep('', 3))

Comment: Hi @SDahm, I would recommend you check the output of `q$data`. There you can see the data of each `geom` where the third is the geom of `geom_signif`. As you can see each facet has three rows that come with the value 3 of. Hope that's more clear.

Comment: Got it. For each 'bracket' there is always a vertical, a horizontal, and a vertical line. Therefore three values for x and xend each. Luckily the y values are already set.